# Ruby Build fail error on Ubuntu 17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

rbenv install 2.2.8

Downloading ruby-2.2.8.tar.bz2...

-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.8.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.8...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.8 is nearing its end of life.
It only receives critical security updates, no bug fixes.

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 17.10 using ruby-build 20170914-19-gdcfa90c)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093.log

Last 10 log lines:
    /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093/ruby-2.2.8/lib/rdoc/generator/ri.rb:26:in `generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093/ruby-2.2.8/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:530:in`block in generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093/ruby-2.2.8/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:525:in `chdir'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093/ruby-2.2.8/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:525:in`generate'
    /tmp/ruby-build.20171209140352.8093/ruby-2.2.8/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:508:in `document'
    ./bin/rdoc:20:in`'

uncommon.mk:427: recipe for target 'rdoc' failed
make: *** [rdoc] Error 1

Answer (score 7):

Tried disabling the doc building step

RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install 2.2.8

it worked